# "Eso es papita pal loro"

Tags: vocabulario, expresiones

¿Qué quiere decir *pal* en esta frase: "Eso es papita pal loro"? Conozco que dicha frase significa que algo es fácil pero la palabra *pal* no la conozco.

Answer (score 4):

*Pa'l* es una contracción popular, no aceptada por la Real Academia Española, que deriva de la unión de la preposición "para" y el artículo "el":

> Eso es papita ***para el*** loro

Popularmente:

> Eso es papita ***pa'l*** loro